# Botão compartilhar

Tags: android, android-activity

E ai pessoal tudo bem? Espero que sim com toda a comunidade Stack.

Bom tenho uma dúvida que ta me matando já tem tempo, e não consigo resolver.
Antes de tudo quero lembrar que sou iniciante em Programação Android.

Quero colocar no meu App um botão ou algum menu de compartilhar, para que as pessoas possam compartilhar o conteúdo de um webview.

Abaixo segue o meus códigos:

**Android Manifest.xmml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".splash_screen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:noHistory="true"
        >
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="radardf.radardf.error_webview"></activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package radardf.radardf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

import radardf.radardf.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//Faz a verificacao da conexao com a internet
//Fim da Verifica��o de conexao com a internet
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);

//Botão de Compartilhamento


//Fim do compartilhamento

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        final WebSettings ws= wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);
        //news implementation
        ws.setSaveFormData(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://urldosite.com.br");
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


        //Barra de Progress StackOverflow
       /* ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog();
        progress.setMessage("Carregando");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.show();*/


        //Barra de Progresso / Carregando
       final ProgressBar Pbar;
        Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                Pbar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                }
            }
        });
        //Fim da Barra de Progresso / Carregando

        //Verifica se a internet está ativa no aparelho
       /* ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ninfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(ninfo!=null && ninfo.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Conectado na internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
                //Caso não tenha internet, Recarrega a SplashScreen
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, splash_screen.class);
                    startActivity(i);
               //Caso não tenha internet, Recarrega a SplashScreen

            Toast.makeText(this,"Sua Internet Precisa estar Ativa. Estamos Tentando conectar...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
*/

        /* Caso a pagina da web não funciona*/
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, radardf.radardf.error_webview.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
         /* Fim:: Caso a pagina da web não funciona*/


        }

//Fecha a Aplicacao Quando pressionar o botao voltar
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   //Fecha a Aplicacao Quando pressionar o botao voltar




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }














}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa usar a função **ShareActionProviders**

Exemplo:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Share"
            android:actionProviderClass=
                "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    ...
</menu>
```

E ai no Java:

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

E o resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o link da [Documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) que explica os detalhes de como deve ser feito.

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo, 
A solução que me enviou acabou dando 99% certo, mas ajudou bastante.

O botão de compartilhamento apareceu, porém não faz nada :(, só fica lá e quando clico não aparece as opções

Answer (score 3):

Para compartilhar algum item basta chamar a intent `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, por exemplo:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String texto = "Olá sou um texto compartilhado"
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Feito isto, irá abrir a janela de compartilhamento padrão do android, isto varia de versão a versão, e poderá compartilhar com todos os Apps registrados.